# Video calling on different pages using WebRTC

Tags: asp.net, .net, real-time, webrtc, video-conferencing

I was following [THIS](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/video-conferencing/) tutorial in order to implement video calling using WebRTC. The example allows people of the same group to communicate using video or audio and it works well. I was wondering if you could Video call people who are on different pages of the same website without having to be on the specific 'video call page' only?

What is the way to allow incoming calls even when you are not joined in a group? I believe it must be a group request (Sending a request to join from Person A to Person B). Is this possible using WebRTC?

Comment: You basically want video calling to work on all pages of a website?

Comment: @ObscureGeek yes! Let's say I call from the Video call page but the users on the home page should receive the call as well

Comment: You don't have to be necessarily be on the video calling page only to receive offers. As long as you are connected to the signalling server you can get the offer message on any page. I believe the code is already written by you all you need to do is identify which portion to migrate to other pages.

Comment: @ObscureGeek would happen to have an example code maybe? This sounds great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebRtc is not based on "who is connected to what page".

The connections only happen through your signalling server logic. This means that any webrtc peerconnection can connect to anyother peerconnection as long as your signalling server relays the connection startup logic(SDPs and Ice candidates).

The webpage is only a way to display the media that you have, the javascript you wrote will run on any page you want.